# Fully circular buttons with dynamic size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create circular buttons in CSS. I use `border-radius: 100%` to make the button look like a circle but it only works if I explicitly set the width and height of the element. But if I do so, the buttons will not adjust to fix larger text

This is what I've tried so far:

```css
.round-button{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.round-button:active{
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="round-button">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="round-button">This text will overflow the button!</button>  
</div>
```

As you can see the first button looks pretty OK, but the text in the second button overflows it. I've used `overflow: hidden` to prevent it from looking ugly but I would like the buttons size to adjust according to the content's size. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean you actually want the button's height to adjust to the contents' width? I'm not sure that's possible

Comment: @MrLister Not just the height but the width too. If more content is added the circle should grow larger while still looking like a perfect circle

Comment: Well, the width is not the problem. Keeping the height/width ratio is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to draw a circle, you need a square to start with .

You can insert a pseudo of an height equal to width using vertical padding with percentage value.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties 
>   
>       The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.
>
> Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be negative. Like margin properties, percentage values for padding properties refer to the width of the generated box's containing block.

Make this pseudo inline-block to help yoy center text.

If text has to wrap a few lines, it needs to be wraped within an inline-block .. if you use an inline-block pseudo.

You can set max and min width too.

example:

```css
.round-button{
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width:120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0;
}
.round-button:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top:100%;
}
span {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-width:90%;
}
.round-button:active{
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="round-button"><span>Button</span></button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="round-button"><span>This text should NOT overflow the button!</span></button>  
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

You are looking for an automatic way of making the width and height equal while it increases its size. If so, I don't **think** there's a way you can do that in CSS. I mean you don't expect `width=height` do you?

I'm not sure but JQuery might be the solution because it has operators and can interact with CSS.

**Edit** After reading the previous answer, I now understand that there's a way to do it in padding. But in my answer I said "I don't think". I loved the solution of @GCyrillus BTW.

Comment: The [answer posted by GCyrillus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37373838/2422013) works perfectly. The following statement you made is completely incorrect: `I don't think there's a way you can do that in CSS`

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen that answer and I never understood padding, never differentiated it from margin tnx anyway : P

Comment: @BenJunior You can read my own explanation about the differences here: http://strictquirks.nl/css/borders.xhtml