# text inside a circle not aligned html css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put text inside a circle. I am struggling to get the text aligned correctly (middle of the circle).

So far the code I've tried was:

css:

```
.circle {
margin:auto;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgb(0, 34, 102);
padding: 10px;
width: 110px;
height: 110px;
margin-top:1px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
<td colSpan=2> <div class="circle"> Discuss <br> ideas and <br> projects </div> </td>
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: maybe this answer could be helpfull too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373734/fully-circular-buttons-with-dynamic-size/37373838#37373838 (not an exact duplicate since text size, so circle size can change ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to horizontally and vertically center your text in the circle. Just use another wrapper div for the text, give it an absolute position with top and left of 50% and translate it back with the [`transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

```css
.circle {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(0, 34, 102);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.circle div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div>
    Discuss
    <br>ideas and
    <br>projects
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're centering it horizontally but not vertically. You could try `position: relative;` or add padding and `text-align: center`.